# Why doesn't adding loading="lazy" with JavaScript work to actually lazy load the images?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I'm able to add the `loading="lazy"` attribute on individual images, or with JavaScript and apply them all at once.

But, when I do it with JavaScript, and then inspect the page, I see the images load on page load, but each image has the attribute attached.

**Why does adding `loading="lazy"` with HTML load the image lazily, but adding the attrib with JavaScript doesn't provide the lazy loading behavior?**

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  let images = img[i];
  images.setAttribute('loading', 'lazy');
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494232410401-ad00d5433cfa">
</div>
```

Comment: The JavaScript doesn't run until after the images have already started loading. So it's too late to make them load lazily.

Comment: So running that particular script in the head would do the trick.

Comment: If you run it in the head then it won't be able to find the DOM elements to change their attributes.

Comment: Any ideas on this? I have many images on my site that I need to apply this to... like hundreds.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it in JS. As soon as the element is loaded into the DOM it starts loading the image unless it already has the `loading="lazy"` attribute. There's no way for your JS to interrupt this.

Comment: Can you delay the creation of the `img` nodes themselves until the JS runs and have it create them with the necessary attribute before insertion? That would avoid the problem with it being in the DOM too early.

Comment: Can you change the `src` attribute before it reaches the browser? if you change `src` to `data-src` the browser won't load it. Then you can add the `loading="lazy"` attribute and then change the `src` to the value of `data-src`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of a catch 22. You need to run the JS before the HTML to set the attribute before it is already loading, but you can't add an attribute to an element that doesn't exist.

You could try creating the image element manually using JS, then adding the attribute, then adding it to the dom.

Maybe something like this:

```js
const imgEl = document.createElement("img");
imgEl.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCVxN.jpg?s=64&g=1"
imgEl.setAttribute('loading', 'lazy');

const body = document.querySelector("body")
body.appendChild(imgEl);
```

Comment: That would be a buttload of javascript... especially for hundreds of images.

Comment: Would also be a lot of html I guess, wrap it into a function so you have some nice one liners.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with html. The question was asking why the JavaScript method behaves as is does. I’m not an expert with SEO so cannot provide accurate info there but I believe the SEO crawlers will allow a page a certain time to load. So if your image loads fast enough then (maybe) it might not have such a negative effect.

Answer (score 2):

The typical solution to this is to use `data-src` attributes instead of `src`.
Then, when you're ready, you switch them to `src` attributes.

That means the images don't get loaded by the browser until you decide.

This is commonly handled by libraries like [`lazysizes`](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). But here's a general concept:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
images.forEach(img => img.src = img.dataset.src);
```

```html
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" loading="lazy">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350" loading="lazy">
```